# Edit worksheet with popup message window open

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using the following macro to open a popup message box pulling in specific cell values. When the message box is open I can't edit the worksheet. When I move my mouse pointer off the message box it turns to a spinning circle. How do I open my message box, have it stay open and edit the worksheet underneath?

```
Sub PopUp()
    Dim vMsg
    Dim r As Integer
    For r = 4 To 16
    vMsg = vMsg & Range("AD" & r).Value & Range("AE" & r).Value & Range("AF" & r).Value & Range("AG" & r).Value & Range("AH" & r).Value & Range("AI" & r).Value & Range("AJ" & r).Value & vbCrLf
    Next
    MsgBox vMsg, , "Values"
End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of using a message box you will need to use something else, like a manually created UserForm, or a new spreadsheet made to hold the information. Message boxes will not allow you to have focus on anything other than the message box.

Comment: You should create a User Form.  The default name is `UserForm1`.  Inside that `PopUp` subroutine you can call `UserForm1.Show vbModeless` and it will pop up but allow you to still edit the worksheet.

Answer (score 4):

The built in `MsgBox` is modal, which means you cannot manipulate the worksheet until the user dismisses, in some fashion, the message box.  The typical workaround appears to be to create your own custom `UserForm` to display the message and call it with `UserForm1.Show vbModeless`, which will display the message and allow the user to still edit the worksheet.

However, there is an alternative way than creating your own custom `UserForm`.  You can use the Windows API instead of the VBA interface.

To do this, start by adding this code to the top of your module (before all subroutines and functions):

```
Private Declare Function MessageBox _
    Lib "User32" Alias "MessageBoxA" _
       (ByVal hWnd As Long, _
        ByVal lpText As String, _
        ByVal lpCaption As String, _
        ByVal wType As Long) _
    As Long
```

The syntax above takes the Windows API function `MessageBoxA` and allows you to call it by calling `MessageBox` (it is aliased).

You can then update your `PopUp` subroutine to use the new `MessageBox` function.

```
Sub PopUp()
    Dim vMsg
    Dim r As Integer
    For r = 4 To 16
    vMsg = vMsg & Range("AD" & r).Value & Range("AE" & r).Value & Range("AF" & r).Value & Range("AG" & r).Value & Range("AH" & r).Value & Range("AI" & r).Value & Range("AJ" & r).Value & vbCrLf
    Next
    MessageBox &H0, vMsg, "Values", vbOkayOnly
End Sub
```

This will allow the user to access the sheet while the message box is displayed.  Additionally, the line:

```
MessageBox &H0, vMsg, "Values", vbOkayOnly
```

Can be changed to

```
MessageBox &H0, vMsg, "Values", vbSystemModal
```

This will allow you to access the sheet, but will keep the message box on top at all times (it will do this for all applications, not just Excel, but nothing is perfect).

The `MessageBox` function takes in four parameters:

- **hWnd** is the special identifier of the window which owns this message box, the trick is to pass in a null with `&H0` so that no window owns it
- **lpText** is the message to be displayed (same as the prompt parameter of the VBA MsgBox function)
- **lpCaption** is the text to be displayed as the title (same as the title parameter of the VBA MsgBox function)
- **wType** is the type of message box that will be displayed (identical to the buttons parameter of the VBA MsgBox function)

You can read more [here](http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=4699).

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, Message boxes are Modal - so they will take the focus until they are dismissed.

The way around this is to create a custom userform which you can use as a messagebox. There is an option on userforms to make them non-modal - which will allow you to carry on with other actions, while they are open.

I hope that this helps

Comment: Application Modal actually; thankfully not System Modal.

Comment: @Jeeped a good point for clarification. There are limits (quite sensibly so) to how Excels VBA objects act.